# Como retirar uma variável da memória?

Tags: c, variáveis, memória, alocação, gerenciamento-de-memória

Como retiro uma variável, não necessariamente do código, mas da memória/registro, em C?

Exemplo hipotético:

```
char meu_byte;
//codigo
deleta_da_memoria(meu_byte);
```

Que gera algo como:

```
pushb 0
; Utiliza o byte
call deleta_da_memoria
```

Ou seja, quero saber qual é processo para deletar uma variável estática em C, considerando as instruções da CPU como informação necessária.

Comment: Se você coloca um exemplo de código que usa o *stack* e aceita uma resposta que fala estritamente sobre o `malloc()` sua pergunta não está clara. Eu já achava que não estava muito, dava margem à interpretações e tentei responder abordando tudo o que dava. Mesmo depois da resposta você nunca disse que era sobre `malloc()`que está interessado. A resposta aceita tanto não responde efetivamente à pergunta feita (e a culpa é da pergunta) que o código postado é completamente diferente da pergunta.

Comment: @bigown a pergunta aceita várias resposta. Simplesmente a escolhida foi a solução.

Comment: Se puderem, adicionem as maneiras OS-only e de escopo nas suas respostas. Também funcionam.

Comment: Se aceita várias soluções, é muito ampla. Mas na verdade o problema mesmo é que você perguntou uma coisa e queria outra.

Comment: @bigown afinal, o que eu quero? Eu quero saber como tirar uma variável da memória em C. Existem 3 maneiras (graças as respostas e às pesquisas eu já conheço), só isso.

Comment: Se você não sabe o que você quer, quem sou eu para saber. Eu só posso dizer o que você perguntou. Você claramente colocou um código que usa *stack*, você não usou um exemplo com *heap* e não falou nisto. Eu até tentei dar uma resposta que olhasse por todos os ângulos e você tentou editá-la dizendo que ela não tinha foco. A sua pergunta não tem foco e você admitiu isto acima. Eu duvido que a resposta que você aceitou lhe ajudou em alguma coisa. Que você vai conseguir fazer alguma coisa com este *assembly*. E se consegue, não teria motivos para perguntar da maneira como perguntou.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Supondo que você atribuiu a memória dinamicamente usando [`malloc()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/malloc/) você libera-lo usando [`free()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/). Se a memória foi alocada estaticamente, você não pode libertá-la.

Segue o código *Assembly* de um pedaço de código escrito em C.

```
00401334  /$ 55             PUSH EBP                                 ; Inicio da pilha
00401335  |. 89E5           MOV EBP,ESP                              ; EBP aponta agora para o topo da pilha
00401337  |. 83E4 F0        AND ESP,FFFFFFF0
0040133A  |. 83EC 20        SUB ESP,20                               ; Espaço alocado na pilha para as variáveis locais
0040133D  |. E8 2E060000    CALL Program1.00401970
00401342  |. C74424 1C 0300>MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+1C],0A             ; Valor utilizado na função abaixo
0040134A  |. 8B4424 1C      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+1C]            ;
0040134E  |. 890424         MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX               ;
00401351  |. E8 92080000    CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.malloc>                ; A função "malloc" é chamada
00401356  |. 894424 18      MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18],EAX            ; Ponteiro para o bloco de memória alocada pela função acima
0040135A  |. 837C24 18 00   CMP DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18],0              ; Verifica se NÃO obtivemos êxito ao alocar memoria
0040135F  |. 75 13          JNZ SHORT Program1.00401374              ; 
00401361  |. C70424 2430400>MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],Program1.00403024 ; puts() recebe como parâmetro a string "Out of memory!"
00401368  |. E8 73080000    CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.puts>                  ; puts() é chamado
0040136D  |. B8 01000000    MOV EAX,1                                ; Coloca em EAX o valor de retorno "1"
00401372  |. EB 48          JMP SHORT Program1.004013BC              ; return 1;
00401374  |> 8B4424 18      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]            ; 
00401378  |. C600 66        MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],66                 ; 66(Hex) 102(Decimal) Ascii "f"
0040137B  |. 8B4424 18      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]            ; 
0040137F  |. 40             INC EAX                                  ; 
00401380  |. C600 6F        MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],6F                 ; 6F(Hex) 111(Decimal) Ascii "o"
00401383  |. 8B4424 18      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]            ; 
00401387  |. 83C0 02        ADD EAX,2                                ; 
0040138A  |. C600 6F        MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],6F                 ; 6F(Hex) 111(Decimal) Ascii "o"
0040138D  |. 8B4424 18      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]            ; 
00401391  |. 83C0 04        ADD EAX,3                                ; 
00401394  |. C600 00        MOV BYTE PTR DS:[EAX],0                  ; "\0"
00401397  |. 8B4424 18      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]            ; 
0040139B  |. 894424 04      MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+4],EAX             ; 
0040139F  |. C70424 3330400>MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],Program1.00403033 ; ASCII "%s"
004013A6  |. E8 45080000    CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.printf>                ; printf() é chamado
004013AB  |. 8B4424 18      MOV EAX,DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+18]            ; 
004013AF  |. 890424         MOV DWORD PTR SS:[ESP],EAX               ; 
004013B2  |. E8 41080000    CALL <JMP.&msvcrt.free>                  ; free() é chamado
004013B7  |. B8 00000000    MOV EAX,0
004013BC  |> C9             LEAVE                                    ; Liberar o espaço usado pela função na pilha
004013BD  \. C3             RETN                                     ; return 0;
```

O código *desmontado* acima é resultado desse trecho de código abaixo.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int nameSize = 10;
    char *name = malloc(nameSize * sizeof(char));

    if (name == 0)
    {
        printf("Out of memory!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    name[0] = 'f';
    name[1] = 'o';
    name[2] = 'o';
    name[3] = '\0';

    printf("%s", name);
    free(name);

    return 0;
}
```

Não sei ao certo se era isso que o *OP* pediu na pergunta mas espero que possa ajudar de alguma forma. Abaixo segue alguns artigos(*em inglês*) que poderão auxiliar você.

1. [The Function Stack](http://www.tenouk.com/Bufferoverflowc/Bufferoverflow2a.html)
2. [C Function Call Conventions and the Stack](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~chang/cs313.s02/stack.shtml)

Comment: Só para testar meus conhecimentos: você está em um sistema 64 bits, Windows, certo? O programa é Test1, mais especificamente...

Comment: :\ tá na hora de estudar mais...

Comment: O Que É OP ?...

Comment: @axell13 *original poster*

Answer (score 8):

Depende do que você quer dizer com "deleta".

Se quer que o valor seja apagado, você pode no máximo zerá-lo, ou seja fazer `meu_byte = 0;`.

Se quer liberar a memória depende de como foi alocado.

Neste caso específico está alocado na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101) portanto a liberação só ocorrerá quando esta variável sair de escopo, ou seja sair do bloco de execução (o que está entre chaves) atual. Você não libera explicitamente a memória do *stack*.

Na verdade a liberação não apaga de fato o valor, o valor é largado lá na memória. Se deseja, talvez por segurança, que nada possa acessar indevidamente este valor mais pra frente - apesar de improvável - você deverá zerá-lo antes de sair do escopo. Muito provavelmente logo em seguida alguma execução vai aproveitar este espaço liberado e jogar alguma coisa por cima, já que tem uma dado lá mas ele foi considerado liberado.

Se tivesse sido alocado com [`malloc()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) no *heap* a liberação deveria ser feita explicitamente com `free()` mas não é o caso e acho que se você estivesse fazendo com `malloc()` saberia usar o `free()`.

Mas provavelmente você está com uma preocupação que não deveria existir. Pelo menos sua pergunta não deixa claro que há algum motivo extra por trás disto. Ou talvez você esteja querendo ser mais esperto que os implementadores de sistemas operacionais, linguagens e compiladores.

Comment: @OP O caso é de alocação de memória. A realidade é que eu estou começando com Assembly e em alguns arquivos C/C++ eu utilizo recursos *inline* (**por isso quero saber a parte por trás do Assembly**). Sim, estou sendo um pouco espertinho, estou fazendo engenharia reversa *hehehehe*. Eu não conheço (sim, conheço, mas não sabia que era o caso) malloc. Justamente por isso não sabia qual era a maneira de alocação. E você sabe: não existe engenharia reversa a não ser em C.

Comment: Existe engenharia reversa em qualquer código em qualquer forma. Em geral não há em *assembly* que faça isso. EU não saberia dizer a implementação exata e pode até variar, mas essencialmente na pergunta que eu *linkei* mostra o funcionamento do *stack*. Basicamente é um ponteiro que em geral fica em um registrar específico do processador que mostra em que posição da pilha vai ser alocado o próximo valor quando for necessário. Quando vai "alocando", o ponteiro vai subindo (ou descendo como gostam alguns) e quando "desaloca" o ponteiro vai na direção contrário. Liberação é só um decremento no SP.

Comment: Recapitulando o que não disse: engenharia reversa **de binários**. O que seria SP?

Comment: [Stack Pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1464035/what-is-a-stack-pointer-used-for-in-microprocessors). É o registrador que eu falei, ficou sem espaço.Você pode fazer uma pergunta :P http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack

Comment: Por que você não faz uma pergunta de Wiki? (Perguntada e respondida pelo mesmo usuário)

Comment: Acho que um semelhante em Assembly é *OS-only*. Dê uma olhada na resposta de "Gunner": http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1659.0

Comment: @LucasHenrique Da uma olhada nessa [página](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames), pode ser do seu interesse.